# How to iterate hierarchical data and output the hierarchy using C#

Tags: c#, .net

given the following class ...

```
public class Category {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Category ParentCategory {get;set;}
}
```

What the most efficient way to output the following from a collection (`IList<Category>`) of Category objects?

```
+ Parent Category
++ Sub Category
++ Sub Category 2
+ Parent Category 2
++ Sub ...
++ Sub ..
++ Sub ....
```

EDIT: Perhaps the real question should be, how should I represent this model in the database and retrieve it using NHibernate?

Comment: Can you tell us what references you already have? If you have only one child, i suspect you can only output it, and all its parents, since you have only a Parent references. There are no child references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to consider reversing your relationship. If a node can get to its parent but not vice versa, you have to have *all* the leaf nodes in order to print out the full tree. Compare this to the situation where you have each node know about its children - then you only need the root node.

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately I'm not sure I can do that with my data access tool (NHibernate). If I could, I would in a second.

Comment: Okay. Will reconsider when I'm back online - but that may be a few hours. Hopefully you'll have good answers by then :)

Do you have any ordering between categories? (I suppose you could always use name...) That might be helpful.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying.  How would you store or work with one vs. the other in a table?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: I'm not sure, offhand - that's probably why I didn't come back to edit my answer. (Bear in mind this was over 4 years ago...) When I wrote my original answer, we didn't know it was meant to be stored in a database. That changes things.

Answer (score 2):

A small recursive function can do it for you.

```
static void recurseCategories(ref List<Category> cl, Category start, int level)
{
  foreach (Category child in cl)
  {
    if (child.ParentCategory == start)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', level) + child.Name);
      recurseCategories(ref cl, child, level + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

My assumptions were:

- You've got an `List` of `Category`. (Of course *all* Category objects you want to print must be in that list. I thought that was self-evident, but seemingly it was not.)
- The root category has a parent of `null`. The initial function call should therefore be `recurseCategories(ref myCategoryList, null, 0)`.
- No orphaned elements exist in your list. Some error handling code should be added.
- Output order will be coherent to whatever order the list is iterated, so apart from the hierarchy it's more or less coincidental.

Comment: That won't work because his elements can only see their parent, but the parent cannot see its children.

Comment: So to clarify, you can walk from one child up to root, but you won't see any other branches of the tree.

Comment: But it just worked for me. Feeding it a list of Categories yielded a nicely intended category tree.

Comment: This works if the List<Category> contains all categories - children and parents. HOwever, if it only contains parents, it won't - but then what would? You'd need another collection of children, and then a variant of this example would work.

Comment: I said so. The question author did not indicate differently. Why do you assume this would not be the case?

Comment: Because that is an absolutely ridiculousness way to store a node datastructure?

Comment: I see. Since you seem to know how to do it right, make a proposal.

Comment: His problem is that he doesn't need a list, only the reference to the root node, and an array in each node of children.

Comment: Agreed. But assume you don't have that data structure from the start, and all you need is indented output. To build a nodes-with-array-of-children structure a similar process would be necessary, so why do it twice?

Answer (score 0):

recently i read about Hierarchical Linq Queries, check out http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2006/07/09/Hierarchical-Linq-Queries.aspx

but I tend to aggree with Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 0):

@Tomalok, when I run your code, with this data structure, I get two nodes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new List<Category>();

        // Example structure from Question
        var fail1 = new Category() { Name = "test1" };
        var fail2 = new Category() { Name = "test2", ParentCategory = fail1 };
        var fail3 = new Category() { Name = "test3", ParentCategory = fail1 };
        var fail4 = new Category() { Name = "test4"};
        var fail5 = new Category() { Name = "test5", ParentCategory = fail4 };
        var fail6 = new Category() { Name = "test6", ParentCategory = fail4 };
        var fail7 = new Category() { Name = "test7", ParentCategory = fail4 };

        foo.Add(fail1);
        foo.Add(fail4);

        recurseCategories(ref foo, null, 0);

    }

    static void recurseCategories(ref List<Category> cl, Category start, int level)
    {
        foreach (Category child in cl)
        {
            if (child.ParentCategory == start)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', level) + child.Name);
                recurseCategories(ref cl, child, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
test1
test4
```

Output should be:

```
test1
   test 2
   test 3
test 4
   test 5
   test 6
   test 7
```

This is because there is no relationship between child nodes that share the same parent.

Comment: Jonathan: In my example of course *all* of the nodes are in the List. Why would you add only two of them?

Comment: @Jonathan: Tomalak is correct here. THe question states that a list of categories is provided - it doesn't state that list only contains parent categories. Assuming it contains ALL categories, including parents and children, Tomalak's code is correct.

Comment: Why the world would you collapse a node structure into an array?

Comment: Why even have parent references at that point? if your going to convert into an array, you might as well just use a count argument for how deep you are in the hierarchy and keep things in order...In other words, He (and I guess you) are doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe because they are stored in a DB table with an Id / ParentId structure and all you have after you select them is a *list of nodes*?

Comment: So read them in properly when you convert your dataset into a list? I'm not going to argue the semantics of it, his design is very flawed, your code works with it...I'd never use either? Ok?

Comment: Who said you should? No need to get pissed.